# angular8 routeguard canActivate does not work

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular8

Recently i update my project from angular7 to angular8,but i got a problem about routeguard.before update the project,it is ok.after that it does not work.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        console.info(1);
        return new Promise<boolean>((resove, reject) => {
            this.authService.judgePass(state.url).subscribe(res => {
                console.info(3);
                switch (res.code) {
                    case -1:
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        resove(true);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.showMsg(res.message);
                        this.router.navigate(['/manage/error']);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.router.navigate(['/operate']);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
        });
    }

   judgePass(route: string): Observable<CommonResult> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/check`;
        console.info(2);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('url', route);
        return this.httpClient.post<CommonResult>(url, formData, {});
    }
```

browser console only print 1 and 2,i expect print all of them, 1,2 and 3.how can i do to get the right answer?Thx,all of you

Comment: The `subscribe()` method takes 3 callback functions. First is *success*, second is *error* and third is *complete*. If there is an error the success method is not called.

Comment: @Reactgular if there is only sucess method ,the subscribe still called,some other part of this project just only using sucess method like the judgePass() method.

Comment: @Reactgular i thought the problem is in the code:new Promise<boolean>...,but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: @Reactgular the rxjs version is 6.4.0

Comment: How can success be called but the console does not print "3". Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Reactgular i mean if i just use:   this.authService.judgePass(state.url).. not in a Promise object,it will print"3", otherwise it will not print"3"